# Preparing a regular expression for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have made this regular expression which does exactly what I want when I test it in e.g. RegExr:

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(test\.yahoo\.com|sub\.yahoo\.com)?(?!([a-z0-9]+\.)?(localhost|yahoo\.com))(.*)?
```

However when I test it in javascript it says that the expression is invalid. After hours of debugging I found out that this expression works in javascript:

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(test\.yahoo\.com|sub\.yahoo\.com)?(?![a-z0-9]+\.)?(localhost|yahoo\.com)(.*)?
```

However this doesn't do what I want (again testing in RegExr).

Why cannot I use the first expression in javascript? And how do I fix it?

**UPDATE JULY 25**

Sorry for the lack of info. The way I am using the Regexp is through a jQuery extension which lets me select using regexp. The script can be seen here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

The specific code I am trying to get to work is:

```
$('a:regex(href, ^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(test\.yahoo\.com|sub\.yahoo\.com)?(?!([a-z0-9]+\.)?(localhost|yahoo\.com))(.*)?)').live('click', function(e) {
```

After including the linked jQuery plugin. The text strings I am testing are:

- http://yahoo.com
- http://google.dk
- http://subdomain.yahoo.com
- http://test.yahoo.com
- http://localhost.dk
- http://sub.yahoo.com/lalala

Where it is supposed to match "http://google.dk", "http://test.yahoo.com" and "http://sub.yahoo.com/lalala" - which it does when using RegExr but failing (invalid expression) using the jQuery plugin.

Comment: Which strings are you going to match? A couple of examples could help.

Comment: what exactly is your goal? You cannot force others to do it the same way as yours, i guess!

Comment: did you try using `RegExp` instead of `RegExr` ? :)

Comment: You didn't read the part of my answer that explains that you must double all the backslashes in your regular expression when it is expressed as a string.

Comment: I did - and even though it is more correct, it does not solve my invalid-expression-problem I am facing.

Comment: **Your expression is not invalid.**

Comment: I'm updating the answer - I think the problem is that that jQuery plugin simply can't work the way it intends with general regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first regular expression is not invalid:

```
var regexp = /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(test\.yahoo\.com|sub\.yahoo\.com)?(?!([a-z0-9]+\.)?(localhost|yahoo\.com))(.*)?/;
```

works fine.

If you want to instantiate the expression from a string, you have to double all the backslashes:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?(test\\.yahoo\\.com|sub\\.yahoo\\.com)?(?!([a-z0-9]+\\.)?(localhost|yahoo\\.com))(.*)?");
```

When you start from a string, you have to account for the fact that the string constant itself uses backslashes as a quoting mechanism, so there will be **two** evaluations made: one as a string, and one as a regular expression.

*edit* — OK I think I see the problem. That plugin you're trying to use is simply attempting to do something that's just not going to work, given the way that Sizzle parses selectors. In other words, the problem is not with your regular expression, it's with the overall selector. It is not even getting far enough to parse the regular expression.

Specifically it seems to be nested parentheses inside the regular expression.  Something as simple as

```
$('a:regex(href, ((abc)))')
```

causes an error. You can instead do something like this:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
  return /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(test\.yahoo\.com|sub\.yahoo\.com)?(?!([a-z0-9]+\.)?(localhost|yahoo\.com))(.*)?/.test(this.href);
}).whatever( ... );
```

Comment: I am fully aware that it is valid - and thus working when using e.g. RegExr. However it it unfortunately not working when I use it it javascript. I have updated the fully details on how I use it.

Comment: I know. So you want me to create a new question where I am a bit more specific, saying using my jQuery selector instead of javascript?

Comment: Have you tried changing your code such that the backslashes in the regular expression are doubled (` \\ ` instead of ` \ `)?  That's almost certainly the problem.